# Proxy Error 408 when running a script written in Scrapy Python

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using a proxy (from proxymesh) to run a spider written in scrapy python, the script is running normally when I don't use the proxy, but when I use it, I am having the following error message:

Could not open CONNECT tunnel with proxy fr.proxymesh.com:31280 [{'status': 408, 'reason': 'request timeout'}]

Any clue about how to figure out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a dashboard at proxymesh that you can look into why the request is being timed out?

Comment: unfortunately no.. on my dashboard I only have general information about traffic and load data

Comment: do you think that the problem is with proxymesh?

Comment: Yes. Since it's taking too long for proxymesh to respond. I expect it could be an issue with proxymesh. Did you try using a different proxy provider?

Comment: No I haven't tryed.. but the weird thing is that proxymesh works for other spiders that I have here

Comment: Got it. Can you paste some code or the URL that you are trying to proxy into with scrapy?

Comment: Thanks.. I figure out here.. the problem is that some proxy location doesn't work with https.. so I just changed it and now it is working.. cheers

Comment: Alright. Add it as an answer. And close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.. I figure out here.. the problem is that some proxy location doesn't work with https.. so I just changed it and now it is working.